# Threading and Polymorphism

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream> 
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
using namespace std; 

class base 
{ 
public: 
    virtual void fun_1() { cout << "base-1\n"; } 
    virtual void fun_2() { cout << "base-2\n"; } 

}; 

class derived : public base 
{ 
public: 
    void fun_1() { cout << "derived-1\n"; } 
    void fun_2() { cout << "derived-2\n"; 
    } 
}; 


class caller
{
    private:
        base *p; 
        derived obj1; 
        p = &obj1;
    public:
        void me()
        {
                std::thread t(std::bind(&base::fun_2, p), this);
                t.join();
        }
};

int main() 
{  
    caller c;    
    c.me();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a written a very simple threading and polymorphism example. All I wanted to do is to call a derived function from a different class which is containing that another class object. The program fails to compile with the message `p does not name a type` which I could not understand why.

Comment: `p = &obj1` doesn't make sense in the body of the class definition. It's a statement, and must be within some function, say `me`.

Comment: You can't have generic statements in the declaration section of a class, all statements must be inside functions. I also think you should read more about *constructor initializer lists* as a way to initialize members (like `p`).

Comment: You don't need `p`, you can pass `&obj1` to `bind`.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you don't need `caller` if all you want to do is explore polymorphism and threads. In `main`: `derived obj1; base *p = &obj1; std::thread t(&base::fun_2, p); t.join();`. The constructor for `std::thread` does just about everything that `std::bind` does.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with threads

Comment: I couldn't delete the question, I did a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in line:

```
p = &obj1;
```

It is better to write like this, it should help:

```
class caller
{
private:
    derived obj1;
    base *p = &obj1;
......
};
```

or initialize pointer in costructor:

```
class caller
{
private:
    derived obj1;
    base *p = nullptr;
    caller() : p(&obj1) {}
......
};
```